# fabric.js - Rotate "Child" Object based on Parent w/o Grouping

Tags: javascript, rotation, fabricjs

Using fabric.js (1.7.11) , I am trying to have one object follow the rotation of another without grouping them, and while maintaining the relative position of the child object to the parent. So I believe I need to (1) set the rotation center of the "child" object to that of the "parent", then (2) as the parent object is rotating, apply that rotation delta to the child ( which may already start in a rotated state ). The end result is such that the child appears "stuck" to the parent ( like a sticky-note on a game-board, and you then rotate the game-board )

Here is the pseudo-code

```
canvas.on('object:rotating', canvasEvent_ObjectRotating);

function canvasEvent_ObjectRotating(e)
{
    // set r2'2 center of rotation = r1's center of rotation

    // r2.angle += ( delta of rotation of r1 angle ) 

}
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/emaybert/bkb5awj6/

Any help with 1 or 2 would be appreciated. Either how to get the angle delta in the object:rotating callback, and/or how to pivot a object around an arbitrary point.  I've seen the reference to `fabric.util.rotatePoint` and an example of how to rotate a Line using it, but not an object, and couldn't make that mental transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you're trying to do? 
https://jsfiddle.net/logie17/ofr8e6qd/1/

```
function canvasEvent_ObjectRotating(e)
{
  origX = r2.getCenterPoint().x;
  origY = r2.getCenterPoint().y;
  let topLeftPoint = new fabric.Point(origX, origY);

  if (!previousAngle) {
    previousAngle = r1.getAngle();
  }
  let angle = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(r1.getAngle() - previousAngle);
  previousAngle = r1.getAngle();
  let center = r1.getCenterPoint();
  let origin = new fabric.Point(r1.left, r1.top);
  let newCoords = fabric.util.rotatePoint(topLeftPoint,origin,angle);

  r2.set({ left: newCoords.x, top: newCoords.y }).setCoords();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Logan. That's fantastic, and 90% there as to what I was looking for. The ultimate solution is to have the blue square rotate "along with" with outer square ( like it does now ) but not have it itself rotate.

Comment: So notice when it starts off the corner of the blue square touches the outer-red square. During rotation, this configuration should stay constant. That point on the blue square is always touching the same point on the red square, regardless of how the red square is rotated.

Comment: The best analogy I can think of is picture a game board resting on a floor. Then attach a sticky note onto the game board. Then rotate the board. ( The sticky note follows the rotation of the board but does not rotate independently )